# Print 42 characters on each line from string

Tags: javascript, qz-tray

**Problem:** I'm using qzTray to print a receipt, earlier i was using html format but the print quality was not good. so i shifted to JavaScript and wrote bunch of functions to print the receipt, i am using this function to print 42 character on each line, i have a string of 105 characters, the string will be printed in 3 lines. I've written some code but its not working entirely, can anyone give me a hint how to do this ?

first line is printed fine but from second line and onward the substr looks like its not working, i don't know why.

Thanks is advance.

```
window.const_alignLeft = '\x1B\x61\x30';
window.const_newLine = '\x0A';

    function getItemRowFull(itemTitle, itemPrice = null) {
        var totalColsPerPage = 42;
        var leftCols = 35;
        var marginSpace = totalColsPerPage === 48 ? '' : '   ';
        if(itemTitle.length > leftCols) {

           leftCols = (!itemPrice) ? totalColsPerPage : leftCols;
           let itemTitleLength = itemTitle.length;
           let receipt = '';
           let startFrom = 0;
           let remainingCharacters = itemTitle.length;
           while (startFrom < itemTitleLength) {
               receipt += const_alignLeft + marginSpace + itemTitle.substr(startFrom, startFrom + leftCols);
               receipt += const_newLine;
               remainingCharacters = (remainingCharacters + itemTitleLength) - (itemTitleLength + leftCols);
               startFrom = (startFrom + leftCols);
           }

           return receipt;
        }
    }
```

**Image** In the image below the function will be used to paragraph related to notes.

[image]

Comment: `itemTitle.match(/[\w\W]{0,48}/g).join(const_newLine);`

Comment: show i replace the entire function with this ?

Comment: Yes, any line that can potentially get long enough to wrap should use a wrapping function.  This gets trickier if you have smaller columns (e.g. text-based table).